# Change of variable

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximation

I have to approximate the following integral, using Simpson's Composite $1/3$ Rule:
    $\displaystyle \int\limits_{0}^1 \mathrm{\frac{e^{2x}}{\sqrt[5]{x^2}}}\,\mathrm{d}x$.
The only problem is that the integral is improper and when I compute it at the value $0$, I get $\frac 1 0$ which is impossible. I can do a change of variable, only I'm not sure how to do it.

How can I change the variable in order to make the integral a proper one?

Comment: How accurate must the answer be?

Comment: It doesn't matter. All I want is to know how to change the integral so that I can apply Simpson's rule on it

Comment: You do not need to change the integral. Is that okay for you?

Comment: But when I replace with 0 I have 1/0. That's why I thought I needed to change the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the improper integral into a proper integral using the change of variables $x = t^{5/2}$.

Then

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\exp(2x)}{x^{2/5}}dx =\frac{5}{2}\int_{0}^{1}t^{1/2}\exp(2t^{5/2})dt $$

Comment: That should work fine, better than mine.

Comment: @bobbym: Thanks. That trick works generally in eliminating the singularity for integrands of the form $x^{-1/n}f(x)$ where $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @RRL: Thank you. It was just what I was looking for.